# Gatsby Background-Image Duplicate Network Image request

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm new to Gatsby and i'm trying to implement the Gatsby Background-image component in my Gatsby react application, querying data from a WordPress site.

Background Image component in article:

[image: Background Image component in article]

When I look at the network developer tool I can see a duplicate request for the same image.

duplicate request of cfa png :

[image: duplicate request of cfa png]

I'm trying to understand if this is expected. i see an initiator from ImageRefs.js.

If this is not expected does anyone know how I might troubleshoot the dup request?

Here is my query in index.js which i get the image src and pass the data down through props to my articles component.

Graphql query:

[image: Graphql query]

I could be misunderstanding the network panel information but this happens for all the images lazy loaded on this page.

Does this have something to do with how I'm passing the image src down into my child article component?

multi image dups:

[image: multi image dups]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @rainer ok i thought i did that. I'll see if i can edit.